# Why are so many numerical parameters in JSON are of string type?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, json

I've been looking at the examples in the documentation and also issuing GET requests via REST to get various information about products and categories. One thing that I find unusual is that there are many numerical parameters which are passed as strings (numbers within quotes) in JSON output. Those are for example, category ids in products. Yet the very same category ids are passed as numbers when you request the catalog structure.

What is the reason behind that and what are the consequences of me passing those numerical parameters without quotes as numbers in POST requests?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the reason behind that

In traditional HTTP, all parameters are strings. This is true for cookie values, GET parameters, POST parameters, etc. Many people who have been coding for the web find it simpler to assume that everything passed across an HTTP connection is a string.

They're not wrong - JSON itself is a string. Though that JSON string can encode a float (Javascript numbers are always 64-bit floating points, even when they don't have an explicit decimal point in the literal) inertia keeps these devs trusting that everything is a string and working from there.

> and what are the consequences of me passing those numerical parameters without quotes as numbers in POST requests?

That would depend on each place that the value is read. You might find that it works in some places and not in others. Being an unsupported "feature", I would not try in production but if you play around with it tell us what you find.

Comment: What is "traditional" HTTP and how does JSON relate to it? You probably mean URI strings, but unless you want to somehow equate the parameters passed in JSON data to parameters passed in URI requests, I don't see how the two are related.

Comment: By traditional HTTP I mean the standards and conventions used in the first years of the web. For reference, I've been dealing with these things since 1998. I would say that JSON formatted HTTP requests and responses were not commonplace before maybe 2012 or so.